# Closing a program using python?

Tags: python

I am trying to use python to close VLC while it is recording audio.  Currently I am using:

```
os.kill(pid,pid)
```

This works but is closing VLC abruptly and not allowing the recording file to close properly, thus corrupting it.  If I manually close the VLC GUI instance than the recording file will not be corrupted.

So basically I am looking for a python command to close an application that emulates the  'Close' button on the application's GUI.

Or, perhaps there is another way. Such as closing the .wav file where the recording is being written, before killing the VLC process?  I also put some work into this, but didn't get any results.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: which OS does this have to work on?

Comment: What signal are you sending? (The signature is `os.kill(pid, sig)`)

Comment: Sorry, I am running on Windows 7, and the pid I am sending in is the actual PID of VLC.

Comment: You should send a [WM_CLOSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close?redirectedfrom=MSDN) message to the VLC process via a [win32api.SendMessage()](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__SendMessage_meth.html) call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working.  Instead of using os.kill() I am using

```
os.system("taskkill /pid " +str(pid)+ " /t")
```

This closes the recording without corrupting the file.  Also if anyone else has this problem and is recording with VLC command line, this does not seem to work if the dummy interface is used.

Comment: `subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/pid', str(pid), '/t'])` is cleaner than using the deprecated `os.system()`.

Answer (score 7):

You're using the function wrong, you'll likely want something like this:

```
from signal import SIGTERM
os.kill(pid,SIGTERM)
```

The second parameter specifies the interrupt. Also often used is `SIGKILL` which is a hard kill, likely same as you had before. You can find more about the linux signals [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html). In windows your options are more limited, see [the python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) for available signals.

By providing `pid` also for the second parameter you probably set a quite heavy kill signal, that terminated the application immediately, without closing files.

Comment: Are you sure `SIGQUIT` is the appropriate signal (it instructs the process to perform a core dump). Reading [libc termination signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) it seems to me `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` would be more appropriate. Other than that, +1 :)

Comment: @LukasGraf: Changed it back to SIGTERM, the info I found on SIGQUIT was a bit confusing, thanks.

Comment: So I am still running into the same problem.  But I will play around with a few other parts of my program and see if I can get this working.  I'll post back after that with my results. Thanks!